# trim string after keyword or a specific character in angular

Tags: javascript, string, angular, url, trim

I have this url

`/application-form?targetDate=2018-03-21`

I want to get the string after the equal sign

How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Using [lastIndexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) and [substr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) methods of string.

```js
const url = '/application-form?targetDate=2018-03-21';

const lastEqualSignIndex = url.lastIndexOf('=');
const datePart = url.substr(lastEqualSignIndex + 1);

console.log(datePart); // -> '2018-03-21'
```

---

**Edited:** multiple query parameters support

Using [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) method of string:

```js
const [, targetDateValue] = '/application-form?targetDate=2018-03-21'.match(/[\?&]targetDate=([^&#]*)/);

console.log(targetDateValue); // -> '2018-03-21'
```

Comment: OP should keep in mind that this doesn't support multiple query parameters. It will always get the value of the last query parameter.

Comment: Yes. Previous solution was targeting the particular case in the question. We can also include the query parameter name in a regex to match only it's corresponding value when there are multiple query parameters. E.g.: `'/application-form?targetDate=2018-03-21'.match(/[\?&]targetDate=([^&#]*)/)[1]`

Answer (score 1):

use split and array

```
var param = "/application-form?targetDate=2018-03-21";
var items = param.split("=");
var arr1 = items[0];
var arr2 = items[1];
var result = arr2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) for this. It's a parser for query strings.

Here's how it's used:

```
new URLSearchParams('?targetDate=2018-03-21').get('targetDate') 

// or if you want to use your URL as-is:
new URLSearchParams('/application-form?targetDate=2018-03-21'.split('?')[1]).get('targetDate')
```

Be aware that this is not supported on IE. For cross-browser variations of this, you can have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/1814486).